# What's wrong with the following proof that almost all real numbers are normal?

Tags: lebesgue-measure, uniform-distribution

Say $U \sim \text{U}[0,1]$. Then $\mathbb{P}[\,U\text{ is normal}\,] = 1$. This is evident from the fact that a Bernoulli process can be used to sample the decimal digits of $U$, leading to a normal number with probability 1. But the probability measure for a uniform random variable is just the Lebesgue measure. Hence almost all numbers in [0,1] are normal. And then all of $\mathbb{R}$ can then be covered by such intervals.

Comment: Sounds correct to me.  Well, except for the details in proving that random digits satisfy the normality property.

Comment: Then why does https://www.colorado.edu/amath/sites/default/files/attached-files/math21-8.pdf require 10 pages of dense formalism to prove the same result and call the proof "elementary"?

Comment: Hmm... it seems there may be more subtlety there than I suspected.

Comment: Sebastian: Do not be too harsh on poor souls, not struck by the Light of Randomness yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with this proof; it is correct (modulo the proof that a Bernoulli process actually produces a normal number, which is an easy consequence of the strong law of large numbers).  More complicated proofs you may have seen are proofs that prove it from first principles without using any machinery from probability theory such as the strong law of large numbers.